# How to change the base URL in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a html file rendered by JavaScript. The JavaScript code will somehow get the base url of the html file and use it to further get other JavaScript codes from the internet.  This is where the problem happens because the base url becomes incorrect when I have downloaded the html file from the website and run it locally in Chrome.

Is there any method to change the base URL universally for JavaScript?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base

Comment: I do not think that you can automatically change the base url, but you can force set it manually (but not permanently). Use `History.pushState()` or `History.replaceState()`

Comment: @Kaiido I have tried but to no avail

Comment: @KenT how did you tried that? It must be set before your scripts try to get the base URI. Now it may also depend on how this script is actually getting that info, but without you telling us more, that the best we can do for you.

Comment: @Kaiido  It works to some extent but doesn't solve my problem behind. I am still exploring.